# microsoft bot framework with node.js plus database and flow

Tags: mysql, node.js, bots, botframework

I would like to create a BOT with Microsoft Bot Framework and I would like to ask few questions about that.

First question is :
What is the best way to designe database if I have questions connected with already defined answers.

For example:
Question -> Answer(2 defined options) -> Question -> Answer(4 defined options) -> Question -> Answer(3 defined options) ... End with some conclusion
So 1 question can have few answers leading to different question.
(If you lead a person through some story).

And second questions is :
How to make a good conversation flow in node.js with Question/Answer thing.
If you can give me some sample code.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If your aim to achieve Question and Answer then I would suggest you the [qnamaker](https://qnamaker.ai/) Provided by Mircosoft.

If you want to manage on database go with the NoSQL database (MongoDB) and internally you can directly search for the question and its answer.

I would suggest go with ***qnamaker*** it will easiest way to do.